# How to binary-search on one field of a List's elements

Tags: java, collections, binary-search, java-stream

Let `C` be a class defined (partially) by

```
private static class C {
    private final int x;
    // lots more fields be here

    public C(int x, /* lots more arguments here */) {
        this.x = x;
        // lots more fields initialized here
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
}
```

and let `cs` be a `List<C>` implementing `RandomAccess`, and sorted on `C.getX()`.

What would be the standard approach to performing a binary search in `cs` for `x1` on `C.getX()`? (In other words, pretending that each element `c` is replaced by `c.getX()` and then we search for `x1` among those integers.)

---

```
Collections.binarySearch(
    cs,
    new C(x1,/* dummy arguments */),
    (a,b) -> Integer.compare(a.getX(),b.getX())
);
```

has the drawback that it requires construction of a new `C` (which may require lots of dummy arguments and knowledge about `C`).

```
Collections.binarySearch(
    cs.stream().map(C::getX).collect(Collectors.toList()),
    x1
);
```

has the drawback that it creates an entire new list and is presumably O(n).

---

Is there a way to search in the stream directly, without collecting it? Or perhaps some other way to search the original list without having to construct a dummy item?

---

In the absence of a better approach, I would do this:

```
public class MappedView<T,E> extends AbstractList<E> {

    public static <T,E> MappedView<T,E> of(List<T> backingList, Function<T,E> f){
        return new MappedView<>(backingList, f);
    }

    private final List<T> backingList;
    private final Function<T,E> f;

    private MappedView(List<T> backingList, Function<T,E> f){
        this.f = f;
        this.backingList = backingList;
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int i) {
        return f.apply(backingList.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return backingList.size();
    }    
}
```

and then

```
Collections.binarySearch(
    MappedView.of(cs, c -> c.getX()),
    x1
);
```

Comment: The binary search algorithm requires a knowledge of the size of the collection, which is not something that can easily be captured within a stream. So you need a collection or an array. I don't think there is a built-in method in the JDK that allows mapping while binary-searching. So your proposed approach (with MappedView) seems to be a reasonable and efficient solution. Unless you can introduce something like `C.getInstance(x1)` to produce a "dummy" C object?

Comment: You should also implement `RandomAccess` on your `MappedView`, or it may not work with `Collections.binarySearch` effectively.  Alternately, you could use `Lists.transform` from Guava, which does all this for you.

Comment: @LouisWasserman This is probably an elementary question but how would I ensure that the `backingList` argument implements both `List` and `RandomAccess`? Do I have to create a new interface for that? (Or is there something like "RandomAccessList" already?)

Comment: @tennenrishin: your best bet is probably just to throw an exception if the list isn't `instanceof RandomAccess`.  Creating a new interface would definitely not help.  (But Guava would take care of that for you by implementing `RandomAccess` if the backing list is `RandomAccess` and not if not.)

Answer (score 5):

Since you are in control of the `Comparator` implementation, you can implement a symmetric comparison function that allows to compare instances of `C` with values of the desired property, i.e. `int` values (wrapped as an `Integer`) in case of your `x` property. It helps to know the factory methods [`comparing…`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) in the [`Comparator` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Comparator.html) which save you from repeating the code for both sides of the comparison:

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(cs, x1,
    Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o instanceof C? ((C)o).getX(): (Integer)o));
```

That way you can search for the `int` value `x1` without wrapping it in a `C` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be this:

```
private static class C {
    private final int x;
    // lots more fields be here

    private C() {
    }

    public C(int x, /* lots more arguments here */) {
        this.x = x;
        // lots more fields initialized here
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public static C viewForX(int x) {
        C viewInstance = new C();
        viewInstance.x = x;
        return viewInstance;
    }
}

Collections.binarySearch(cs, 
    C.viewForX(x1), 
    (a,b) -> Integer.compare(a.getX(),b.getX()));
```

Or, if you don't mind a dependency, you can do this with [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

```
List<Integer> xs = Lists.transform(cs, C::getX());
Collections.binarySearch(xs, x1);
```